# UIBezierPath Custom lineCapStyle different on both Ends

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath, cashapelayer, cgpath

What i want to achieve is 
[image]

**What i tried** is to draw three arcs with different colors with lineCapStyle `.rounded`. My code for drawing these arcs are below

```
 private func circularActivityPath(rect:CGRect, configuration:PathConfiguration)-> CGPath {

            let center = CGPoint(x: rect.maxX / 2, y: rect.maxY / 2)
            let longestSide = rect.height < rect.width ? rect.height : rect.width
            let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: (longestSide / 2) - (configuration.lineWidth / 2), startAngle: configuration.startAngle.deg2rad() , endAngle: configuration.endAngle.deg2rad(), clockwise: true)

            path.lineCapStyle = .round
            return path.cgPath
        }

     override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

         let config1 = PathConfiguration(color: .red, lineWidth: lineWidth, startAngle: CGFloat(-90), endAngle: CGFloat(10), type: .track , shape: shape )
        let trackLayer1 = CAShapeLayer()
            trackLayer1.drawActivityCircles(in: rect,  configuration: config1)

        let config2 = PathConfiguration(color: .blue, lineWidth: lineWidth, startAngle: CGFloat(25), endAngle: CGFloat(80), type: .track , shape: shape )
        let trackLayer2 = CAShapeLayer()
        trackLayer2.drawActivityCircles(in: rect,  configuration: config2)

        let config3 = PathConfiguration(color: .green, lineWidth: lineWidth, startAngle: CGFloat(95), endAngle: CGFloat(255), type: .track , shape: shape )
        let trackLayer3 = CAShapeLayer()
            trackLayer3.drawActivityCircles(in: rect,  configuration: config3)

          self.layer.addSublayer(trackLayer2) // blue
          self.layer.addSublayer(trackLayer3) // green
          self.layer.addSublayer(trackLayer1) // red

    }
```

where `PathConfiguration` is a struct

```
struct PathConfiguration {
    let color: UIColor
    let lineWidth: CGFloat
    let startAngle: CGFloat
    let endAngle: CGFloat
    let type: TrackType
    let shape: TrackShape
}
```

What i get is below with rounded caps on both sides... i want to achieve one rounded and one arc cap on respective ends. i will be very thankful to you if i get some pointers how i can get the same shape

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the below code to achieve this result.

```
import UIKit
// MARK: - Enums
public enum AnimationStyle: Int {
    case animationFanAll
    case animationFan
    case animationFadeIn
    case animationthreeD
    case none
}

public enum PercentageStyle : Int {
    case none
    case inward
    case outward
    case over

}
open class Circular: UIView {

    // MARK: - Public Properties
    public var animationType: AnimationStyle {
        get {
            return _animationType
        }
        set(newValue) {
            _animationType = newValue
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    public var showPercentageStyle: PercentageStyle {
        get {
            return _showPercentageStyle
        }
        set(newValue) {
            _showPercentageStyle = newValue
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    public var lineWidth: CGFloat {
        get {
            return _lineWidth
        }
        set(newValue) {
            _lineWidth = newValue
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    //  MARK:- Private Variable

    private var _percentages: [Double]

    private var _colors: [UIColor]

    private var _lineWidth = CGFloat( 10.0)

    private var _animationType: AnimationStyle

    private var _showPercentageStyle: PercentageStyle



    //MARK:- draw

    override public func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        var startAngle = -90.0

        for i in 0..<_percentages.count {

            let endAngle = startAngle + ( _percentages[i] * 3.6 ) - 4

            let shapeLayer =   self.addArac(with: _colors[i], in: rect, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle)
            showAnimationStyle(index: Double(i), shapeLayer: shapeLayer, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle)
            showPercentages(midAngel:startAngle + (endAngle - startAngle)/2, percentage: _percentages[i])

            startAngle = (endAngle + 4 )
        }

    }

    //MARK:- inializer

    public init(percentages:[Double],colors:[UIColor],aimationType:AnimationStyle = .animationFanAll , showPercentageStyle: PercentageStyle = .none) {

        self._percentages = percentages
        self._colors = colors
        self._animationType = aimationType
        self._showPercentageStyle = showPercentageStyle
        super.init(frame:CGRect.zero)
        self.backgroundColor = .clear
        self.clipsToBounds = false
    }

    required public init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        // super.init(coder: coder)
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


    //MARK:- Animations Functions
    private func showAnimationStyle(index:Double,shapeLayer:CAShapeLayer,startAngle:Double,endAngle:Double) {

        switch _animationType {
        case .animationFanAll:
            maskEachLayerAnimation(startAngal: startAngle, endAngal: endAngle + 4 , shape: shapeLayer)
        case .animationFan:
            if Int(index) == _percentages.count - 1 {
                maskAnimation()
            }
        case .animationFadeIn:
            oppacityAnimation(index: index, shape: shapeLayer)
        case .animationthreeD:
            transformAnimation(index: index, shape: shapeLayer)
        case .none:
            break

        }
    }

    private  func oppacityAnimation(index:Double,shape:CAShapeLayer) {
        shape.opacity = 0
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + Double(index)/2.5 ) {
            shape.opacity = 1
            let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
            animation.fromValue = 0
            animation.toValue = 1
            animation.duration = 1
            shape.add(animation, forKey: nil)
        }
    }

    private func transformAnimation(index:Double,shape:CAShapeLayer){
        shape.opacity = 0
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + Double(index)/2.5 ) {
            shape.opacity = 1
            let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform")
            animation.fromValue = CATransform3DMakeScale(0, 0, 1)
            animation.toValue = CATransform3DIdentity
            animation.duration = 1
            shape.add(animation, forKey: nil)
        }
    }

    private func maskEachLayerAnimation(startAngal:Double,endAngal:Double,shape:CAShapeLayer){

        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = max( bounds.maxX,bounds.maxY)/5
        shapeLayer.frame = bounds
        let center = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)
        let longestSide = max(bounds.height,bounds.width)
        shapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: longestSide/2, startAngle: CGFloat(startAngal).deg2rad(), endAngle: CGFloat(endAngal ).deg2rad(), clockwise: true).cgPath
        shapeLayer.strokeEnd = 0
        shape.mask = shapeLayer

        addAnimationToLayer(toLayer: shape, fromLayer: shapeLayer)

    }

    private func maskAnimation() {

        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = max( bounds.maxX,bounds.maxY)/2
        shapeLayer.frame = bounds
        let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x:bounds.midX,y:bounds.midY), radius:max( bounds.maxX/2,bounds.maxY/2), startAngle: CGFloat(-89.0).deg2rad(), endAngle: CGFloat( 270.0).deg2rad(), clockwise: true)

        shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
        shapeLayer.strokeEnd = 0
        self.layer.mask = shapeLayer

        addAnimationToLayer(toLayer: self.layer, fromLayer: shapeLayer)

    }

    private func addAnimationToLayer(toLayer:CALayer , fromLayer:CAShapeLayer) {

        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
            toLayer.mask = nil
        }

        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
        animation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + 0.3
        animation.fromValue = 0
        animation.toValue = 1
        animation.fillMode = .forwards
        animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        animation.duration = 1
        fromLayer.add(animation, forKey: "line")

        CATransaction.commit()

    }

    //MARK:- show percentages
    private func showPercentages(midAngel:Double, percentage:Double) {

        guard let radius = getRadiusOfPercentage() else {
            return
        }

        let center = CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX / 2, y: bounds.maxY / 2)

        let  x = center.x  + (radius) * CGFloat(cos(CGFloat(midAngel).deg2rad()))
        let  y = center.y  + (radius) * CGFloat(sin(CGFloat(midAngel).deg2rad()))


        let percentageLabel  = UILabel(frame: CGRect.zero)
        percentageLabel.frame = CGRect.zero
        percentageLabel.text = String(percentage)
        percentageLabel.textColor = .black
        percentageLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 12)
        percentageLabel.sizeToFit()
        percentageLabel.center = CGPoint(x:x,y:y)
        addSubview(percentageLabel)
        percentageLabel.alpha = 0

        var delay = 1.5
        if self.animationType == .none {
            delay = 0
        }

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: delay, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            percentageLabel.alpha = 1
        })
    }

    private func getRadiusOfPercentage() -> CGFloat? {
        let longestSide = max(bounds.height,bounds.width)
        switch self.showPercentageStyle {
        case .inward:
            return longestSide/3 - lineWidth
        case .over:
            return longestSide/2 - lineWidth
        case .outward:
            return longestSide/2  + lineWidth + 5
        case .none:
            return nil
        }
    }

    //MARK:- Drawing Code

    private func addArac(with color:UIColor ,in rect:CGRect, startAngle:Double , endAngle:Double)-> CAShapeLayer {

        let center = CGPoint(x: rect.maxX / 2, y: rect.maxY / 2)

        let longestSide = max(rect.height,rect.width)

        let lineWidth = CGFloat(self._lineWidth / 20)

        let smallCircleRadious = (longestSide / (2 + lineWidth))

        let startAngle = CGFloat(startAngle)

        let endAngle = CGFloat(endAngle)

        let outerRadious =  (longestSide / 2)

        let midPoint = (longestSide / (2 + lineWidth/2.7))

        let path = UIBezierPath()

        let  x3 = center.x  + (outerRadious) * CGFloat(cos(startAngle.deg2rad()))
        let  y3 = center.y  + (outerRadious) * CGFloat(sin(startAngle.deg2rad()))


        let  x4 = center.x  + (smallCircleRadious) * CGFloat(cos(startAngle.deg2rad()))
        let  y4 = center.y  + (smallCircleRadious) * CGFloat(sin(startAngle.deg2rad()))


        let  x5 = center.x  + (midPoint) * CGFloat(cos((startAngle + self._lineWidth * 0.5).deg2rad()))
        let  y5 = center.y  + (midPoint) * CGFloat(sin((startAngle +  self._lineWidth * 0.5).deg2rad()))

        path.move(to: CGPoint(x:x4,y:y4))
        path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x:x3,y:y3), controlPoint: CGPoint(x:x5,y:y5))

        path.addArc(withCenter:center, radius:outerRadious, startAngle: startAngle.deg2rad()  , endAngle: endAngle.deg2rad(), clockwise: true)

        let  x1 = center.x  + (outerRadious) * CGFloat(cos(endAngle.deg2rad()))
        let  y1 = center.y  + (outerRadious) * CGFloat(sin(endAngle.deg2rad()))

        let  x6 = center.x  + (midPoint) * CGFloat(cos((endAngle + self._lineWidth * 0.6).deg2rad()))
        let  y6 = center.y  + (midPoint) * CGFloat(sin((endAngle + self._lineWidth * 0.6).deg2rad()))

        let  x2 = center.x  + (smallCircleRadious) * CGFloat(cos(endAngle.deg2rad()))
        let  y2 = center.y  + (smallCircleRadious) * CGFloat(sin(endAngle.deg2rad()))


        path.move(to: CGPoint(x:x1,y:y1))
        path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x:x2,y:y2), controlPoint: CGPoint(x:x6,y:y6))
        path.addArc(withCenter:center, radius: smallCircleRadious, startAngle:  endAngle.deg2rad(), endAngle: startAngle.deg2rad(), clockwise: false)


        let shape = CAShapeLayer()
        shape.frame = bounds
        shape.lineCap = .round
        shape.fillColor = color.cgColor
        shape.path = path.cgPath
        layer.addSublayer(shape)

        return shape

    }
}
extension CGFloat {
    func deg2rad() -> CGFloat {
        return self * .pi / 180
    }
}
```